# Elixir: Resume code execution after reaching IEx.pry

Tags: elixir

In ruby `Ctrl - d` allows to resume the execution of the code after reaching a `binding.pry`.
What is the equivalent in Elixir for `IEx.pry` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As documented in [`IEx.pry/0`](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#pry/0), you can call `respawn` to resume the execution.

> This is useful for debugging a particular chunk of code when executed by a particular process. The process becomes the evaluator of IEx commands and is temporarily changed to have a custom group leader. Those values are reverted by calling `IEx.Helpers.respawn/0`, which starts a new IEx shell, freeing up the pried one.

```
iex(1)> defmodule A do
...(1)>   require IEx
...(1)>   def a do
...(1)>     a = 1
...(1)>     b = 2
...(1)>     IEx.pry
...(1)>     IO.puts a + b
...(1)>   end
...(1)> end
{:module, A,
 <<70, 79, 82, 49, 0, 0, 12, 144, 66, 69, 65, 77, 65, 116, 85, 56, 0, 0, 0, 110,
   0, 0, 0, 12, 8, 69, 108, 105, 120, 105, 114, 46, 65, 8, 95, 95, 105, 110,
   102, 111, 95, 95, 9, 102, 117, 110, 99, ...>>, {:a, 0}}
iex(2)> A.a
Break reached: A.a/0 (iex:6)
pry(1)> a
1
pry(2)> b
2
pry(3)> respawn

Interactive Elixir (1.5.1) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
3
:ok
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [continue/0](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/1.14.0/IEx.Helpers.html#continue/0) function, which is intented for resume the execution of the current process.