# resume execution after IEx.pry()

Tags: elixir

How to exit debugging without restarting the session?

After the `respawn` command, I lose all previously initialized variables.

```
Interactive Elixir (1.7.3) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> defmodule Test do
...(1)> require IEx
...(1)> def test do
...(1)> s = "Hello"
...(1)> IEx.pry()
...(1)> "#{s}, World!"
...(1)> end
...(1)> end
{:module, Test,
 <<70, 79, 82, 49, 0, 0, 13, 144, 66, 69, 65, 77, 65, 116, 85, 56, 0, 0, 0, 142,
   0, 0, 0, 15, 11, 69, 108, 105, 120, 105, 114, 46, 84, 101, 115, 116, 8, 95,
   95, 105, 110, 102, 111, 95, 95, 7, 99, ...>>, {:test, 0}}
iex(2)> a = 1
1
iex(3)> Test.test
Break reached: Test.test/0 (iex:5)
pry(1)> s
"Hello"
pry(2)> respawn

Interactive Elixir (1.7.3) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
"Hello, World!"
iex(1)> a
** (CompileError) iex:1: undefined function a/0
```

Comment: Did you try `continue`?

Comment: @JonasDellinger after continue I can not enter anything, just exit the iex via ctrl + c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391388/elixir-resume-code-execution-after-reaching-iex-pry

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it as it is stated in the documentation https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.Helpers.html#respawn/0
It starts just a new process which has nothing to do with the previous one

Answer (score 0):

> How to exit debugging without restarting the session?

The [continue/0](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/1.14.0/IEx.Helpers.html#continue/0) function, which is intented for resume the execution of the current process. So it does not restart the process as the respawn/0 function does.

> After the respawn command, I lose all previously initialized variables.

It's not possible to reuse previous variables or assign new values to the ones you're debugging